# Why does same procedural texture look different on different objects

Tags: materials

[image]See attached image to see this frustrating issue. I modeled a sound bar, subwoofer, and a desktop speaker that I duplicated. I want to create a procedural texture that looks something like the weave/mesh you find on some speakers. I realize my example is nowhere near a mesh, I'm showing it like this to illustrate my issue better. The same material appears quite different on all these objects. Why? I've tried unwrapping and adjusting the mapping coordinates, but nothing makes the material appear consistent across the various devices, the way I'd like it to. I'm desperate for help! Thank you so much in advance!

[Link to my blender file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hs6SyHk8-5fafZOpQpevcgEjTxrbk4VL/view?usp=sharing) - The issue is with the material titled 03 Weavr. Thanks again!

Comment: because your UV unwrap needs to be correct and consistent, otherwise the result will be scaled and stretched. Maybe you could also try another Texture Coordinate output like Object? But maybe share your file

Comment: Thanks for your reply moonboots! I switched the texture coordinate to Object and it looks like it helped but where the big radius curved surfaces are it still looks a little inconsistent. I'll post the Blender file for you to dig in and have a look at. Thanks so much!

Comment: I added a link to my Blender file above. Thanks, Moonboots!

Comment: Hello, your link asks for an authorization

Comment: Whoops! Refresh and try again. Should work now.

Comment: Have your tried going to object mode > unwrap > uv unwrap?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple unwrap but choose *Conformal* instead of *Angle Based*:

[image]

You could also use the *Texture Coordinate Object* output instead of the *UV* output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO MUCH, Moonboots! Your suggestions solved my problem. I really appreciate your help and your quick response – amazing! So grateful!